# Foreign key issue in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a table called plan_submissions which has a foreign key referencing the advisors table.  I am sure the foreign key syntax is correct because I am using identical syntax in another part of my project which works.  I believe the issue I have is that the advisors table is created after the plan_submissions table.

Code from plan_submissions table:

```
        Schema::create('plan_submissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('advisor_id')->index();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->foreign('advisor_id')->references('id')->on('advisors');
```

Code from advisors table:

```
        Schema::create('advisors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
```

Is there anyway to fix this without deleting my plan_submissions table simply to put it after the advisors table in migration order?

Comment: You concrete problem is very unclear. You can not create a foreign key to a table that does not exists, you can rearrange migrations by changing the file name.

Comment: well it didn't create `plan_submissions` table anyway because of the foreign key error ... the migrations are named with a timestamp in the beginning, adjust that so it would be after the advisors migration

Comment: What is the error message are getting?

Comment: Migrations run alphabetically so you can just rename the migration file to something that comes before

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
$table->foreign('advisor_id')
->references('id')
->on($tableNames['advisor'])
->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure you need the `->index()` method as the foreign key will add it's own

```
$table->bigInteger('advisor_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('advisor_id')->references('id')->on('advisors');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$table->foreign('advisor_id')->references('id')->on('advisors')
              ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');
```